# ifstream to get then next character

Tags: c++, while-loop, character, ifstream

So I have a while look that checks every character in a file.

```
while (infile.get(ch))
```

The problem is that in the same loop I have to check the next character to check for some validation.

Is there anyway I could move the next character while keeping track of the current one?

Thanks

Comment: Use `peek()` for this.

Comment: how would I do that??

Comment: infile.peek(ch)?? is the next character?

Comment: You call it with zero arguments and it returns the next pending character in the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `peek()` method so you will be able to look at the next character before extracting it. Here's an example:

```c++
std::istringstream iss("ABC");

for (char c; iss.get(c); )
{
    std::cout << "Current character is: " << c << std::endl;

    if (iss.peek() != EOF)
        std::cout << "Next character is: " << (char)iss.peek();
}
```

This should output:

```
 Current character is: A
 Next character is: B
 Current character is: B
 Next character is: C
 Current character is: C
```